# amp-ad passing utm key values from request parameters to DFP

Tags: amp-html

I want to pass query parameters to an amp-ad tag of type "doubleclick". I have read the targeting information here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad

and the link related to how I think it should be done for Double Click:

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/rtc-documentation.md

It's not clear to me how I should pass parameters that came in my query string. I noticed there are other AMP tags that can have a QUERY_PARAM that would replace on rendering, but it doesn't seem to be the case for the amp-ad tag.

I am trying something like this:

```
<amp-ad width=300 height=250
type="doubleclick"
data-slot="/slot_id/ad_unit_id"
json="{'targeting':{ 'utm_source':[QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)]}}">
```

Is there another way of passing key-value pairs to DFP that have values from the query string?

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) {
  $utm_source = '["'.$_GET['utm_source'].'"]';
}

echo '<amp-ad width=300 height=250
type="doubleclick"
data-slot="/slot_id/ad_unit_id"
json="{'targeting':{ 'utm_source':'.$utm_source.'}}">';
```

Comment: once the AMP page is generated, it's cached. I don't think server side scripting to generate the AMP page is the solution here, since every person will view the same AMP code, it's probably something on the client side.